# Check csv field for text size and convert to bytes

Tags: bash, csv, sed, import

I receive a small CSV that usually contains 20-50 rows with 4 fields on a linux host.  The 3rd field is required to be byte size but I find it often is in human readable format and extra spaces preceding the value.  Is there a simple way to remove leading blank spaces and convert that 3rd field into the closest byte value (rounding is ok) if it contains human readable text?  Example below.

```
"3","3","  5815","User 1"
"6","12"," 788MB","User 2"
"2","4"," 983KB","User 3"
"25","4","1600MB","User 4"
"647","201","  19GB","User 5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","                                   # field delimiter
    a[""]=1                                      # none is one
    a["KB"]=kilo=1024                            # KB defined
    a["GB"]=kilo*(a["MB"]=(kilo*(kilo)))         # defining MB and GB
}
{
    gsub(/^" *| *"$/,"",$3)                      # remove quotes and space
    match($3,/[KMG]B/)                           # extract the term
    $3="\"" $3*a[substr($3,RSTART,RLENGTH)] "\"" # lookup and multiply
}1' file                                         # output
```

Output

```
"3","3","5815","User 1"
"6","12","826277888","User 2"
"2","4","1006592","User 3"
"25","4","1677721600","User 4"
"647","201","20401094656","User 5"
```

It only works for KB, MB and GB. Define more if needed. Also, my KB is old school 1024 B's, change that when you leave the 20th century. ;D

Comment: That works perfectly and with your comments I will be able to mod for larger sizes with inserting a similar definition and also changing the match line to [KMGT].  I'm also oldschool and use 1024 so all good there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & numfmt):

```
sed -E "s/\"\s*([0-9]+[KMG]?)B?\"/\"'\$(numfmt --from=iec \1)'\"/3;s/.*/echo '&'/e" file
```

Remove padding of the 3rd field and the letter `B` if present and replace with a shell interpolated `numfmt` command using its value. Then `echo` the entire line which will invoke the the inserted command.

Alternative:

```
sed 's/\([KMG]\)B/\1/;' file | numfmt -d \" --from=iec --field 6
```